# 32bit DLLs using MSDTC/oracle XA on 64 bit Win2k3

Tags: vb6, oracle10g, msdtc, wow64, xa

I have a COM+ application (mostly vb6 based), that I need running on a 64-bit system. It's supposed to communicate with an oracle database (10g, 32bit). Everything works fine when I disable XA, but when I have it enabled I receive the following error;

> The XA Transaction Manager called the
>   "GetXaSwitch" function in the XA
>   resource manager DLL. The call to the
>   "GetXaSwitch" function failed:
>   File=d:\nt\com\complus\dtc\dtc\xatm\src\xarmconn.cpp
>   Line=2503.

My oracle client is 10g 32-bit.

I don't know a lot about 32bit/64bit compatibility, but I do see that my application is calling the MSDTC dlls located in the WOW64 part of the registry ([hklm/software/wow6432node/microsoft/msdtc/mtxoci]), while it access the XADLL located in the native 64-bit part of the registry ([hklm/software/microsoft/msdtc/xadll])

So I tried to change the references in there to be 32-bit dlls, but then they would not load.

Does anyone have any ideas at all on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this can often be a permissions issue (See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816633).

Comment: Appreciate the input, but it does not appear to be about permissions. I've duplicated the system on a 32 bit system and it works well. Also I was super liberal on granting rights on my test system, so that should be covered.